# AngularJS ui-router child to parent view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router-extras, angular-ui-router

I'm having routing issues with child to parent navigation.

My routing configuration is as follows:

```
 templateApp.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

//For Default Redirect
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

//For set up the states
$stateProvider
    .state('list', {
        url: "/",
        cache:false,
        templateUrl: "/Templates/TemplateList",
        controller: "templateListController"
    })
    .state('template', {
        url: "/template/:templateId",
        cache: false,
        templateUrl: "/Templates/MainTemplate",
        controller: "mainTemplateController"
    })
    .state('template.detail', {
        url: "/detail/:templateId",
        cache: false,
        templateUrl: "/Templates/TemplateDetails",
        controller: "templateDetailController"
    })
    .state('template.section', {
        url: "/section/:paperTemplateId",
        cache: false,
        templateUrl: "/Templates/TemplateSection",
        controller: "templateSectionController"
    })
    .state('template.summary', {
        url: "/summary/:templateId",
        cache: false,
        templateUrl: "/Templates/TemplateSummary",
        controller: "templateSummaryController"
    });

}]);
```

where I want to navigate to the `template` state from 'list state'. I have use following code and it working perfectly.

```
    $state.go('template', { templateId: examTemplate.Id });
```

When I want to navigate to the 'template.detail' state I have use following code and it is working perfectly.

```
    $state.go('template.detail', { templateId: $scope.templateId });
```

Now from the child "template.detail" I want to navigate "to template" state. So I have used following code.

```
        $state.go('template', { templateId: $scope.templateId });
```

But this routing is not working. Could you please someone show me the issue with that code when I routing child to parent.

Thanks,
Erandika

Answer (score 1):

Your answer lies in the [ui-router doc](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state). It says :

- $state.go('contact.detail') - will go to the contact.detail state
- $state.go('^') - will go to a parent state
- $state.go('^.sibling') - will go to a sibling state
- $state.go('.child.grandchild') - will go to grandchild state

Hence, use "^" sign to go to parent state of the current state.

Comment: Hi manashi, Actually I already tried to do it according to doc. But it does not work.

Comment: @Erandika Sandaruwan can you paste the controller code, which tries to change the state to its parent?